# How do I compare the effect a binary or categorical variable has on a binary target variable between groups?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, binary-data

I have a dataset with three levels:

1. on the lowest level there are news articles
2. on the mid level, news articles belong to news outlets
3. on the highest level, news outlets are grouped by a categorical variable

Each news articles can belong to only one news outlet and each news outlet can belong to only one high-level group. The target variable is binary, whether the news article was mentioned on social media or not. On the news article level we have one independent binary feature (e.g., whether the article is about a certain topic or not). The news outlets have different numbers of articles (some have only 1 and some have a few thousand). The high-level groups have different numbers of news outlets (some have ~50 and some have ~200).

I'm interested (1) to evaluate whether the binary topic variable on the news article level has an influence of the likelihood of the article being mentioned. Further I'm interested (2) to evaluate whether the effect the topic variable has on the likelihood of an article being mentioned depends on the high-level group/ differs between the high-level groups.

| Group | News Outlet | News Article | Topic | Mentioned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1A1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | A | 1A2 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | B | 1B1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | C | 2C1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | C | 2C2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | C | 2C3 | 0 | 0 |

UPDATE:
Assuming that the high-level group is not actually a group but a IV on the news outlet level (2nd lvl), I ran the following glmm to answer (1)

```
model0 <- glmer(y ~ 1+topic+(1+topic|noutlet), data=data, family="binomial")

summ(model0)

MODEL INFO:
Observations: 2442747
Dependent Variable: y
Type: Mixed effects generalized linear regression
Error Distribution: binomial
Link function: logit 

MODEL FIT:
AIC = 1113846.38, BIC = 1113909.92
Pseudo-R² (fixed effects) = 0.00
Pseudo-R² (total) = 0.66 

FIXED EFFECTS:
------------------------------------------------
                     Est.   S.E.   z val.      p
----------------- ------- ------ -------- ------
(Intercept)         -3.38   0.08   -41.83   0.00
topic                0.17   0.02     8.55   0.00
------------------------------------------------

RANDOM EFFECTS:
-----------------------------------
  Group     Parameter    Std. Dev. 
--------- ------------- -----------
 noutlet   (Intercept)     2.54    
 noutlet      topic        0.27    
-----------------------------------

Grouping variables:
---------------------------
  Group    # groups   ICC  
--------- ---------- ------
 noutlet     1132     0.66 
---------------------------
```

which suggests a positive influence of the topic IV on the target variable.

Further I ran the following glmm for question (2):

```
model <- glmer(y ~ 1+topic*bias+(1+topic|noutlet), data=data, family="binomial")

summ(model)

MODEL INFO:
Observations: 2442747
Dependent Variable: y
Type: Mixed effects generalized linear regression
Error Distribution: binomial
Link function: logit 

MODEL FIT:
AIC = 1113593.09, BIC = 1113758.31
Pseudo-R² (fixed effects) = 0.13
Pseudo-R² (total) = 0.65 

FIXED EFFECTS:
-----------------------------------------------------------
                                Est.   S.E.   z val.      p
---------------------------- ------- ------ -------- ------
(Intercept)                    -4.69   0.12   -40.49   0.00
topic                           0.22   0.04     4.90   0.00
biasLeft                        3.68   0.28    13.10   0.00
biasLeft-Center                 2.16   0.17    12.91   0.00
biasRight                       2.44   0.34     7.15   0.00
biasRight-Center                1.38   0.21     6.60   0.00
topic:biasLeft                 -0.12   0.08    -1.58   0.11
topic:biasLeft-Center          -0.07   0.05    -1.34   0.18
topic:biasRight                 0.05   0.09     0.52   0.60
topic:biasRight-Center         -0.08   0.06    -1.28   0.20
-----------------------------------------------------------

RANDOM EFFECTS:
-----------------------------------
  Group     Parameter    Std. Dev. 
--------- ------------- -----------
 noutlet   (Intercept)     2.20    
 noutlet      topic        0.26    
-----------------------------------

Grouping variables:
---------------------------
  Group    # groups   ICC  
--------- ---------- ------
 noutlet     1132     0.60 
---------------------------
```

With

```
print(summary(pairs(emmeans(model_eqvar, ~ bias*topic, type = "response"), by="bias", reverse=TRUE), by=NULL, infer=c(TRUE,TRUE)))

contrast        bias         odds.ratio     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL null z.ratio p.value
topic1 / topic0 Least Biased       1.24 0.0552 Inf     1.109      1.39    1   4.905  <.0001
topic1 / topic0 Left               1.10 0.0693 Inf     0.936      1.29    1   1.521  0.4969
topic1 / topic0 Left-Center        1.16 0.0328 Inf     1.078      1.25    1   5.209  <.0001
topic1 / topic0 Right              1.30 0.0987 Inf     1.071      1.58    1   3.473  0.0026
topic1 / topic0 Right-Center       1.14 0.0536 Inf     1.015      1.29    1   2.890  0.0191

 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: sidak method for 5 estimates 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log odds ratio scale 
P value adjustment: sidak method for 5 tests 
Tests are performed on the log odds ratio scale
```

We see that the increases in y due to topic are significant for almost all biases. However, ultimately, I would be interested in determining whether the increases are significantly different between biases. Would comparing contrasts of contrasts be suitable to answer that question? E.g.,

```
print(summary(pairs(pairs(emmeans(model_eqvar, ~ bias*topic, type = "response"), by="bias", reverse=TRUE), by=NULL), by=NULL, adjust="mvt", infer=c(TRUE,TRUE)))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on #3? What is the grouping variable and how many high level groups do you have?

Comment: News outlets are grouped/ characterized according to their political bias. Each news outlet is described with one of 5 political bias categories. I assume that this is not even a 3rd-levl grouping but rather a level-2 IV. For each bias we have a 50 to 200 news outlets.